# If $T: V \to W$ is an isomorphism, then there are bases $B$ and $B'$ such that $[T]_{B',B}$ is the identity matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

> Suppose $V$ and $W$ are finite-dimensional vector spaces and that $T: V \to W$ is an isomorphism. Then there exist bases $B$ and $B'$ for $V$ and $W$ respectively such that $[T]_{B',B}$ is the identity matrix.

I have no idea how to start this question, I thought of making a basis for V... But I'm stuck after that. =/

Comment: **Hint**: Choose a basis $\mathcal{B}$ for $V$, and show that $\mathcal{B}' = \{T(b) : b \in \mathcal{B}\}$ is a basis of $W$ with the desired properties.

Comment: The proof asks you to essentially show that bases for $B$ and $B'$ exist such that $T$ is the identity matrix. So essentially, you've got an existence proof. A good place to start is with the definition of an isomorphism, and show that as a consequence of this definition, such bases **must** exist.

Comment: So would I let $\beta = {v_1, v_2, ... , v_n}$ and find the basis for $\beta'$ by showing that $T(a_1*v_1 + a_2*v_2 + ... + a_n*v_n) = 0$?

Answer (score 3):

Let $B=(e_1,\ldots,e_n)$ a basis of $V$ then since $T$ is an isomorphism $B'=(T(e_1),\cdots,T(e_n))$ is a basis of $W$ and it's clear that $[T]_{B',B}$ is the identity matrix.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* The image of a generating set under an epimorphism is a generating set. The image of a linear independent family of vectors under a monomorphism is a linear independant family.